# Escaping macro parameter value in Freemarker

Tags: java, escaping, freemarker

Consider the following macro

```
<#macro subject text>
${_mail.setSubject(text)}
</#macro>
```

and example usages:

```
<@mail.subject text="MyEmailSubject124" />
<@mail.subject text="${initiator!'<unknown>'}: Subject with interpolation" />
```

Now, my application should be able to write specific Freemarker template files including lines with that macro. However, the "text" parameter value is retrieved from user input via UI. So when building the template file content I have code like

```
"<@mail.subject text=\"" + escape(userInput) + "\" />"
```

But how should I **escape the parameter value**?

I tried with `StringUtil.FTLStringLiteralEnc(subject, '"')` from `freemarker.template.utility` package but that didn't work for the interpolation example because it produced

```
<@mail.subject text="$\{initiator!'\lunknown\g'}: Subject with interpolation" />
```

and interpolation wasn't done. I did not find out which escaping is to be used here.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems that you intend to allow the user to enter arbitrary FreeMarker expressions, because you intend to allow `${expression}`. Then the user uses FTL syntax in `userInput`, so escaping is meaningless. If the user has the power to enter arbitrary expressions, only they know what they mean with that expression, and hence where to escape things *inside* it. (Escaping makes sense if you want to prevent the user to enter an expression, which is what `FTLStringLiteralEnc` did.)

Comment: I agree that the user is somehow an expert that knows how to use freemarker syntax. The problem is that he could enter something like `subject" /> muhahah <anytag ` or similar to destroy the macro call. Also, the user shouldn't care about escaping the `"` character somehow. This is where our application should escape user input such that the user do not have to know where the user input is integrated in the template.

Comment: Maybe a good compromise is that you only escape outside `${...}` (and `#{...}`), and leave the inside of `${...}` as is. That requires you to slice up the input, and then re-assemble it. There's no such method included. You will still remain "vulnerable" to things written inside the `${...}`. But then, being able to write somewhat complex logic is the point of using FreeMarker. You can also parse the `${...}` part to check for unclosed things, so they won't become a harder to understand error when it's inserted into the template.

Comment: Your compromise sounds ok for me. Do you have a link to a documentation which explains which escaping should be done in the macro parameter value outside of interpolations? Im not sure how to implement it.

Comment: As you insert this inside an FTL string literal, use `FTLStringLiteralEnc` for the parts outside the interpolation. BTW, the hardest part is figuring out where the end of the interpolation is, as you can't just look for the first `}`.